# Video scrambled display in Adobe Air

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, video, video-streaming, flex4.6

I have two Flex applications that I am attempting to use to display the same video (one at a time, of course!). One of these applications is a web client that displays the video using a VideoDisplay. The other is an Air application that also uses a VideoDisplay to display the same video.

The web application displays the video without problems. hhe Air application displays a rather impressive screwed- up color display that does not even resemble the content of the video.

Is there a driver or something that is missing from my Air application? Curiously, I tried this same application on another machine and it displays the video! It seems to work on one machine but not the other. Both machines are running Windows 7.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? Please advise...

Comment: Have you tried different `renderMode`s? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS901d38e593cd1bac-3d719af412b2b394529-8000.html

Comment: This was an interesting idea, so I tried it. I changed the renderMode tag in the app.xml file. It made no difference in the display. It is still screwed up. Thanks anyway...